# Open a second instance as administrator?

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I not-infrequently find myself wanting to run an app as an administrator, when I already have an instance of it open, which I don't want to close (for instance, notepad or cygwin).

With no instances open, I can right-click on the icon in the task bar and choose 'Run as Administrator'. However, when an instance is already open, right-clicking only gives me options dealing with that window (resize, close, etc), not for opening a new instance as an administrator.

How can I open a new instance of an application as an administrator?

Comment: The behavior is entirely up to the program.  Lots of programs only allow a single instance to be ran.

Comment: Please read what I said.  The application either allows or prevents multiple unique instances of itself.  In your examples the application dos not prevent it.  I figured you knew how to "run as administrator" due to you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an application allows to run a 2nd instance, there are various ways to start it.

The easiest way is to use the taskbar entry itself.

Rightclick the app, then from the list you get find the application itself. Now hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then right-click the app to get the popup. It'll give you the `Run as Administrator` option as well.
[image]